# Imitating split view animation used in iOS Calendar app

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, uicollectionview, jtapplecalendar

[image]I am currently experimenting with a [calendar framework](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) I found online which possesses most of the functionality I need. However, I would really like to add a feature similar to the animation in the iOS Calendar where when a date is tapped, the view splits at that location and the selected week moves to the top of the calendar. Its an intuitive way to display info about the selected day. I just need some suggestions as to how this can be achieved since I'm not super familiar with collection views.

The calendar is a grid collection view with months as different sections from what I understand. Is it possible to just stick a supplementary view anywhere in a collection view dynamically? Or maybe I should look into adjusting insets at a specific location? I'm really not sure what direction to take and could use some suggestions.

[Here](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/expandable-uitableviewcells) is sort of what I want to do but with a table view.

Comment: you want the whole calendar to animate fold? or just a date cell

Comment: Not concerned about the type of animation. Just want to get the calendar to split at a specific location. After doing a bunch of research though, I think this is currently out of the scope of my abilities. Going to just go another route

Comment: I have one last question. You said you wanted your animation to look like -> [this](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/expandable-uitableviewcells). Cant you just use their code? Or do you have a problem converting it to swift? I have just used their code and Made my calendar split right down the middle just like it is done in their code. Do you want my solution?